# Fetch column where time clashes in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here, I need to fetch the row when the time clash occurs

char datatype for DATE, START_TIME and END_TIME

```
        RECORD_ID                 DATE     START_TIME  END_TIME 
1. "00MS740720210616000001"    "20210701"    "0930"     "1930"
2. "00MS740720210616000003"    "20210701"    "1230"     "1830"
```

I have used the below query

```
SELECT * from TIME_DATA where DATE ='20210701' and start_time >='0830' and end_time <='1830'
```

The output of the above query is row number 2

```
        RECORD_ID                 DATE     START_TIME  END_TIME 
1. "00MS740720210616000001"    "20210701"    "0930"     "1930"
```

But the time clash occurs for both rows.

My desired ouptut is

```
        RECORD_ID                 DATE     START_TIME  END_TIME 
1. "00MS740720210616000001"    "20210701"    "0930"     "1930"
2. "00MS740720210616000003"    "20210701"    "1230"     "1830"
```

Comment: Please define "time clash".

Comment: "SELECT * from TIME_DATA where DATE ='20210701' and start_time >='0830' and end_time <='1830'". In this query start and end time thus intersect with start and end time of both the records in the table. This I meant as time clash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for intersections of time, use `exists`:

```
select td.*
from time_data td
where exists (select 1
              from time_data td2
              where td2.date = td.date and
                    td2.end_time > td.start_time and
                    td2.start_time < td.end_time
              );
```

Comment: Here i need to pass values date, start_time and end_time.

Comment: @Manoj . . . Just filter in the outer query.